# ¿Cómo modificar el padding de un contenedor para mostrar una a una las imágenes contenidas dentro de él en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Quisiera saber si se puede hacer un `slide-show` modificando el padding del contenedor de las imágenes. Es decir, cuando se le vaya dando click al botón de siguiente, que el contenedor de las imágenes vaya adquiriendo un padding mayor para que se posicionen una a una las imágenes y que cuando llegue a la imagen final que se haga un bucle para que regrese a la inicial.

No sé si se podrá, he intentado pero solo se he hecho que se muevan 2 imágenes y no se como hacer que se muestren una por una cuando se le de click a los botones.

```js
function init() {
  document.getElementById("btn_next").onclick = siguiente;
  document.getElementById("btn_prev").onclick = Izquierda;
}
init();

function siguiente() {
  document.getElementById("cont_img").style.paddingLeft = "400px";
}

function Izquierda() {
  document.getElementById("cont_img").style.paddingLeft = "1200px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.centrarflex {}

.main_conten {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-left: 1200px;
}

.btn_prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-170px, 170px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.btn_next {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(170px, 170px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="centrarflex">
  <div class="main_conten">
    <div id="cont_img" class="group">
      <img id="imagen1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/37/a0/6137a0b858af6cec81cc5910467d21ad.jpg" alt="sskama">
      <img id="imagen2" src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6465/442c541129a5d1b1bba6221872e85dcf41b775f4_hq.jpg" alt="sskama">
      <img id="imagen3" src="http://pm1.narvii.com/6055/2eae41d4253b0a9296d9c14e4df90ae5833e7352_hq.jpg" alt="sskama">
      <img id="imagen4" src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6567/84b9b654e31c3f1071cf8c77f760533e4e855f65_hq.jpg" alt="sskama">
    </div>
    <div id="btn_prev" class="btn_prev"> ← </div>
    <div id="btn_next" class="btn_next"> → </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: estas reescribiendo la funcion onClick, deberias de cambiar la siguiente linea a : `document.getElementById("btn_next").onclick(siguiente);`

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow, lo que está haciendo el compañero es usar [la propiedad onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) (que por defecto no está definida), en este caso no está usando [el método click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) o algún otro método o función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es posible, lo que te recomendaría usar mejor transformaciones `CSS` en vez de `padding`, ya que el primero logra animaciones más fluidas debido a que usa la GPU si está disponible.

Tu ejemplo solo funciona con dos imágenes porque solo tienes dos valores en tu código, uno cuando haces click en `siguiente` y otro cuando haces click en `izquierda`. Si quieres que funcione con todas las imágenes, y para evitar tener que crear condiciones con diferentes valores para cada imagen, lo mejor es que dinámicamente se generen los valores que se necesitan utilizar al inicio, se guarden en un array, y utilizar dicho array para aplicar esos valores cada vez que se haga click en `siguiente` o `izquierda`.

> He variado un poco el código `CSS` para hacerlo más conciso.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('cont_img');
var images = container.querySelectorAll('img');
var total = images.length;
var transforms = Array.apply(this, {length: total}).map((img, i) => `translateX(${-i * 400}px)`);
var index = 0;

function siguiente() {
  index++;
  if (index === total) { index = 0; }
  container.style.transform = transforms[index];
}

function izquierda() {
  index--;
  if (index < 0) { index = total - 1; }
  container.style.transform = transforms[index];
}

document.getElementById("btn_next").onclick = siguiente;
document.getElementById("btn_prev").onclick = izquierda;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main_conten {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;  
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.btn_prev,
.btn_next {
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
}

.btn_prev { left: 0; }
.btn_next { right: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="centrarflex">
  <div class="main_conten">
    <div id="cont_img" class="group">
      <img id="imagen1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/37/a0/6137a0b858af6cec81cc5910467d21ad.jpg" alt="sskama">
      <img id="imagen2" src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6465/442c541129a5d1b1bba6221872e85dcf41b775f4_hq.jpg" alt="sskama">
      <img id="imagen3" src="http://pm1.narvii.com/6055/2eae41d4253b0a9296d9c14e4df90ae5833e7352_hq.jpg" alt="sskama">
      <img id="imagen4" src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6567/84b9b654e31c3f1071cf8c77f760533e4e855f65_hq.jpg" alt="sskama">
    </div>
    <div id="btn_prev" class="btn_prev"> ← </div>
    <div id="btn_next" class="btn_next"> → </div>
  </div>
</div>
```